# Relationship Count (Number) Needed

Tags: relationships

I have 2 channels, "vehicle" and "make".  Vehicle uses a text input channel field, make uses a dropdown select channel field.

In the "vehicle" channel I also have a relationship field to "make".

I would like to have a count for how many times I have set a vehicle to a particular make.  Let's take Acura for example.  I have entered in 20 Acura cars, and 5 Nissan cars. I would like to show 20 next to Acura.

And perhaps a total_count would be good too, of all of the vehicle+make relationships that are combined.  (25)

Can this be done relatively easily in EE 2.9.2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `{relationship_field:total_results}` to get the total results with `relationship_field` changed to whatever your field name is for your relationship field.

There are a bunch of parameters you can further use to further filter your results in the [Relationship documentation.](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/relationships.html)

Comment: The relationship field is "rel__vehicle_make", and my code is {rel__vehicle_make:total_entries} but It doesn't appear to be working.  No output or anything, just blank.

Comment: Any ideas what might be wrong with the code or EE setup? Thank you!
:)

Comment: They using `:total_results` not `:total_count` as you have posted it.

Comment: Indeed it should be `{rel_vehicle_make:total_results}` and not `:total_entries`